# Update of individual pod shows errors for another pod (Branch.io)

Tags: ios, cocoapods, branch.io

having an odd issue. I'm running pod update on an individual pod and when I try to run my app I get a bunch of errors all related to Branch (Branch.io. It seems to have created the file BNCConfig.m that wasn't there before. The file is like so:

```
#include "BNCConfig.h"

NSString * const BNC_API_BASE_URL    = @"https://api.branch.io";
//NSString * const BNC_API_BASE_URL  = @"https://ahmed.api.beta.branch.io";

NSString * const BNC_API_VERSION     = @"v1";
NSString * const BNC_LINK_URL        = @"https://bnc.lt";
NSString * const BNC_SDK_VERSION     = @"0.12.24";
```

I get the error `Expected identifier or '('` and `Expanded from macro 'BNC_API_BASE_URL'`. I get the same errors for `BNC_API_VERSION` and `BNC_LINK_URL`. The macros are in `BNCConfig.h` like so:

```
//
//  BNCConfig.h
//  Branch-SDK
//
//  Created by Qinwei Gong on 10/6/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Branch Metrics. All rights reserved.
//

#ifndef Branch_SDK_Config_h
#define Branch_SDK_Config_h

#define SDK_VERSION             @"0.12.14"

#define BNC_PROD_ENV
//#define BNC_STAGE_ENV
//#define BNC_DEV_ENV

#ifdef BNC_PROD_ENV
#define BNC_API_BASE_URL        @"https://api.branch.io"
#endif

#ifdef BNC_STAGE_ENV
#define BNC_API_BASE_URL        @"http://api.dev.branch.io"
#endif

#define BNC_LINK_URL             @"https://bnc.lt"

#ifdef BNC_DEV_ENV
#define BNC_API_BASE_URL        @"http://localhost:3001"
#endif

#define BNC_API_VERSION         @"v1"

#endif
```

I'm really not sure what is going on here. The `BNCConfig.m` didn't exist at all before I did pod update on an unrelated pod. Oddly enough if I just remove `BNCConfig.m` from the project the app runs. Is it safe to just remove this file? Any ideas why it is suddenly appearing and causing issues? I have tried removing the pod, and doing pod install. I have also cleared derived data and cleaned the project.

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch here:

It looks like you somehow have ended up with two different versions of the Branch SDK in your project. Not sure how that happened!

Try this:

1. Delete/move the **pods** directory from your project.
2. Run `pod install` to get a fresh copy of everything.